# how to add a installed app shortcut to a listview in my ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello I am trying to make a app that when a user click's the add button opens another page that list's of all installed app's on that device then by clicking on a single app adds that app to the main page in a listview of my app and then the user can go back to the main page and click that app and it opens it from my app. I am using ionic 3 and am using the [AppAvilability](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability) plugin to list all installed apps
 here's my code for the main page:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only solid>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
         //add redirect to applist here
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only solid>
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page1">
  <div class="spacer" style="height:30;" id="page1-spacer6"></div>
  <ion-list id="page1-list1">
    <ion-item color="none" href-inappbrowser="http://www.google.com" id="page1-list-item5">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/FUhCAggEQECSHctkev1s_web.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>
        Internet
      </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="spacer" style="height:12;" id="page1-spacer1"></div>
  <ion-list id="page1-list2">
    <ion-item color="none" id="page1-list-item6">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/SWDHBJ2JRJyhl2rDAbPe_email.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>
        Email
      </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="spacer" style="height:12;" id="page1-spacer2"></div>
  <ion-list id="page1-list3">
    <ion-item color="none" on-click="goToMath()" id="page1-list-item7">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/eRWr6of9Sq2eRPvM4LjM_math.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>
        Math
      </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="spacer" style="height:12;" id="page1-spacer3"></div>
  <ion-list id="page1-list4">
    <ion-item color="none" on-click="goToScience()" id="page1-list-item8">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/Xtvlww5aS4SeDvBnE1FJ_sci.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>
        Science
      </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="spacer" style="height:12;" id="page1-spacer4"></div>
  <ion-list id="page1-list5">
    <ion-item color="none" on-click="goToHandwriting()" id="page1-list-item9">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/eeisx650TqaSAMPn9EH4_handwrittin.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>
        Handwriting
      </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="spacer" style="height:12;" id="page1-spacer5"></div>
  <ion-list id="page1-list6">
    <ion-item color="none" on-click="goToFlashcards()" id="page1-list-item10">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/noKqBQE1QbKdexCASz5g_flashcards.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>
        Flashcards
      </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div>
    <img src="assets/img/My3SIjXBSFoRJZG6yaWI_haQq7TIJRYeYrFNGbcvw_books.png" style="display:block;width:auto;height:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I'm new to ionic so any links/code samples on how to do would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Store all the apps in some sort of array. For example, you could make an array of object were each app has certain properties (a name etc.). Using *ngFor, you could list these in a view.

To push a page onto the navigation based on an entry you will want to import the NavController and NavParams. After that, create a page from the CLI using `ionic g page appPage` Then, you can inject the NavController and call .push('appPage') when the user clicks a button. Here is where you will want to push some data to the Navparams (navigation parameters) about which page was clicked. You can google "Angular Tour of Heroes" and follow the "detail view" guide they have on there so that you can associate each page in the list with a name of some sort.

After that, simply design your HTML and Typescript for the AppPage page to get a clean looking detailed pageview.